# The camel context initiates shutdown immediately after application start, with no apparent error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

My spring-boot app starts a Camel route that consumes from a Kafka-enabled Azure event hub. Immediately after the message that the Application has started, this message is logged: "INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.24.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down".

Then any in-flight exchanges (if they exist) are successfully processed by the Camel route, and eventually the route is shutdown (gracefully), which also terminates the app.

No error messages are shown, nothing seems to be wrong, except that the shutdown is initiated automatically right after the application starts....

Any idea why this happens ?

I have played around with the timeouts for Kafka, but there's no change in behavior.

I have set the logging level to TRACE, but still I don't see why shutdown is initiated.

Among others, I use these libraries: spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-starter-web, azure-servicebus-spring-boot-starter, camel-kafka, camel-spring-boot-starter, camel-undertow-starter

This is how the route starts:

```
            from("kafka:dummytopic?brokers=dummy.servicebus.windows.net:9093&topic={{event.hubs.hub.magento}}&groupId={{event.hubs.consumer-group}}"
                    + "&consumersCount=1"
                    + "&autoOffsetReset=latest"
                    + "&saslMechanism=PLAIN"
                    + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
                    + "&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2"
                    + "&sslEnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"
                    + "&sslEndpointAlgorithm=HTTPS"
                    + "&saslJaasConfig=" + saslJaasConfig
                    + "&autoCommitEnable=true")
.....
```

Normally the route should keep running and polling the kafka Event Hub for events (and process them when they are available).

Instead, it initiates shutdown immediately (still successfully processing any in-flight exchanges) - it simply shuts down gracefully. No error messages.

Any help is appreciated!

PS: this is an extract from the trace log:

```
15:01:40.867 [main] INFO  c.i.s.n.NotificationMicroserviceApplication - Started NotificationMicroserviceApplication in 10.516 seconds (JVM running for 14.643)
15:01:40.868 [main] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camelContext'
15:01:40.868 [main] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
15:01:40.868 [main] DEBUG o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication@22aefae0]
15:01:40.870 [main] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camelContext'
15:01:40.870 [main] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
15:01:40.870 [main] DEBUG o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication@22aefae0]
15:01:40.872 [Thread-37] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2cd2a21f, started on Thu Jun 06 15:01:31 EEST 2019
15:01:40.873 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties'
15:01:40.873 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'systemProperties'
15:01:40.873 [Thread-37] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String
15:01:40.874 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camelContext'
15:01:40.874 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
15:01:40.875 [Thread-37] DEBUG o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2cd2a21f, started on Thu Jun 06 15:01:31 EEST 2019]
15:01:40.877 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camelContext'
15:01:40.877 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] TRACE o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping bean 'camelContext' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext]
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.24.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] TRACE org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper - Stopping service org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@108b121f
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] TRACE org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper - Shutting down service org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@108b121f
15:01:40.879 [Thread-37] TRACE o.a.camel.support.ServiceSupport - Service already stopped
15:01:40.880 [Thread-37] INFO  o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
15:01:40.880 [Thread-37] TRACE o.a.c.m.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy - Checking whether to register org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@11ee4d34[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask] from route: null
15:01:40.880 [Thread-37] DEBUG o.a.c.i.DefaultExecutorServiceManager - Created new ThreadPool for source: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy@58b97c15 with name: ShutdownTask. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@11ee4d34[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask]
15:01:41.073 [Thread-37] TRACE o.a.c.u.c.CamelThreadFactory - Created thread[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] -> Thread[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask,5,main]
15:01:41.075 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] DEBUG o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - There are 1 routes to shutdown
15:01:41.075 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] TRACE o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Shutting down route: routeEventHub with options [Default,CompleteCurrentTaskOnly]
```

You can see that at 15:01:40.872 it starts closing things down...

Comment: you can specify `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` see https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

Comment: See also ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12868

Comment: I added ```camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true``` but I  get the same result...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, for me case the solution it was add the next depency into pom file.

`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no thread that keeps the application alive. That's why it immediately shutsdown.

You may want to add spring-boot-starter-web to have a web container that is running or you could have a loop in our main class that prevents the shutdown.

I would go for the web container. So you could also add the actuator framework with some diagnostic information.

Comment: I already had the spring-boot-starter-web dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Adding a web container "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency into my spring-boot project solved a similar issue that I was having. Thanks @Simon

Comment: I dont think that any of these will be a recommended way of doing this. What about adding camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, this solution worked:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class NotificationMicroserviceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotificationMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("You can press Ctrl+C anytime to shutdown application");
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't work on local as junit wont stop  and the build continuous going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to spring version upgrade.

The problem described is related to conflicts between different Maven dependencies. I've had the same problem while trying to use the latest version of Spring Boot with Apache Camel.

After analyzing the dependency tree, it turned out that the version of spring-webmvc was 5.2.9, while all other spring dependencies were of version 5.2.8.

I have solved the problem by using a newer version of camel-spring-boot-dependencies (3.6.0)